# Saving custom objects in swift & cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want to save a custom object (containing an array of custom object that again contains custom objects and an uncountable amount of properties from your standard integer to 3d byte arrays). 
So serializing everything and somehow encode all this recursively to convert it to data with NSKeyedArchiver would be such a huge pain, isn't there an easy c like way where I can just save and load my main object as a binary somewhere on the hd?

Something like:

```
//save
NSData.makeBinaryStuffOutOf(myObject).saveIt(atSomeLocation) 
//and 
NSData.loadMyStuffAt(someLocation) as! myCustomClassThing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> isn't there an easy c like way where I can just save and load my main object as a binary somewhere on the hd?

Think for a moment, how would you do it in C?

*If* your data resided in a single contiguous block of memory and contained no internal pointers then you could `write(2)`/`read(2)` the memory block.

*However* if there were internal pointers, or multiple blocks of memory involved then you'd need to write something which could encode/decode this structure to/from a sequence of bytes...

and that would be a bit of work, even in C...

or you could use code someone else has already written...

like `NSKeyedArchiver`

> So serializing everything and somehow encode all this recursively to convert it to data with `NSKeyedArchiver` would be such a huge pain

The point about the archiver classes is they provide all the framework, you just need to write a single archive/unarchiver routine per class and it all just then works...

HTH